# Scipy: bounds for fitting parameter(s) when using optimize.leastsq

Tags: python, scipy

I am using optimize.leastsq to fit data. I would like to constrain the fitting parameter(s) to a certain range. Is it possible to define bounds when using optimize.leastsq? Bounds are implemented in optimize.fmin_slsqp, but I'd prefer to use optimize.leastsq.

Answer (score 6):

I think the standard way of handling bounds is by making the function to be minimized (the residuals) very large whenever the parameters exceed the bounds.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
def residuals(p,x,y):
    if within_bounds(p):
        return y - model(p,x)
    else:
        return 1e6

p,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = optimize.leastsq(
    residuals,p_guess,args=(x,y),full_output=True,warning=True)
```

Comment: You mean, adding an if-condition that returns a high value, rather than the actual residual, in case (one of) the fit parameters are/is outside of the bounds?

Answer (score 3):

I just found this a short time ago

http://code.google.com/p/nmrglue/source/browse/trunk/nmrglue/analysis/leastsqbound.py

It uses parameter transformation to impose box constraints. It also calculates the adjusted covariance matrix for the parameter estimates.

BSD licensed, but I haven't tried it out yet.

Comment: Transformation is a good approach.  Here is a [MATLAB file](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd) that does it; it is well commented so the (relatively simple) math involved is clear.

Comment: I tested it and it works if you just give it the right kind of function, but it was made to follow the syntax of leastsq from scipy.optimize so it should be no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might find
    https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/
useful for this.  It allows upper / lower bounds for each variable, and allows algebraic constraints between parameters.