# Python parameter transformation according to MINUIT

Tags: python, constraints, scipy, bounds

I am writing an automated curve fitting routine for 2D data based on scipy's optimize.leastsq, and it works. However when adding many curves with starting values slighly off I get non-physical results (negative amplitude, for example).

I found this post [Scipy: bounds for fitting parameter(s) when using optimize.leastsq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7409694/scipy-bounds-for-fitting-parameters-when-using-optimize-leastsq) and was trying to use the parameter transformation according to Minuit from Cern. In the above mentioned question somebody provided a link to some python code.

```
code.google.com/p/nmrglue/source/browse/trunk/nmrglue/analysis/leastsqbound.py
```

I wrote this minimal working example (extending the code)

```
"""
http://code.google.com/p/nmrglue/source/browse/trunk/nmrglue/analysis/leastsqbound.py
Constrained multivariate Levenberg-Marquardt optimization
"""

from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #new

def internal2external_grad(xi, bounds):
    """ 
    Calculate the internal to external gradiant

    Calculates the partial of external over internal

    """

    ge = np.empty_like(xi)

    for i, (v, bound) in enumerate(zip(xi, bounds)):

        a = bound[0]    # minimum
        b = bound[1]    # maximum

        if a == None and b == None:    # No constraints
            ge[i] = 1.0

        elif b == None:      # only min
            ge[i] = v / np.sqrt(v ** 2 + 1)

        elif a == None:      # only max
            ge[i] = -v / np.sqrt(v ** 2 + 1)

        else:       # both min and max
            ge[i] = (b - a) * np.cos(v) / 2.

    return ge

def i2e_cov_x(xi, bounds, cov_x):

    grad = internal2external_grad(xi, bounds)
    grad = grad = np.atleast_2d(grad)
    return np.dot(grad.T, grad) * cov_x


def internal2external(xi, bounds):
    """ Convert a series of internal variables to external variables"""

    xe = np.empty_like(xi)

    for i, (v, bound) in enumerate(zip(xi, bounds)):

        a = bound[0]    # minimum
        b = bound[1]    # maximum

        if a == None and b == None:    # No constraints
            xe[i] = v

        elif b == None:      # only min
            xe[i] = a - 1. + np.sqrt(v ** 2. + 1.)

        elif a == None:      # only max
            xe[i] = b + 1. - np.sqrt(v ** 2. + 1.)

        else:       # both min and max
            xe[i] = a + ((b - a) / 2.) * (np.sin(v) + 1.)

    return xe

def external2internal(xe, bounds):
    """ Convert a series of external variables to internal variables"""

    xi = np.empty_like(xe)

    for i, (v, bound) in enumerate(zip(xe, bounds)):

        a = bound[0]    # minimum
        b = bound[1]    # maximum

        if a == None and b == None: # No constraints
            xi[i] = v

        elif b == None:     # only min
            xi[i] = np.sqrt((v - a + 1.) ** 2. - 1)

        elif a == None:     # only max
            xi[i] = np.sqrt((b - v + 1.) ** 2. - 1)

        else:   # both min and max
            xi[i] = np.arcsin((2.*(v - a) / (b - a)) - 1.)

    return xi

def err(p, bounds, efunc, args):

    pe = internal2external(p, bounds)    # convert to external variables
    return efunc(pe, *args)

def calc_cov_x(infodic, p):
    """
    Calculate cov_x from fjac, ipvt and p as is done in leastsq
    """

    fjac = infodic['fjac']
    ipvt = infodic['ipvt']
    n = len(p)

    # adapted from leastsq function in scipy/optimize/minpack.py
    perm = np.take(np.eye(n), ipvt - 1, 0)
    r = np.triu(np.transpose(fjac)[:n, :])
    R = np.dot(r, perm)
    try:
        cov_x = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(np.transpose(R), R))
    except LinAlgError:
        cov_x = None
    return cov_x


def leastsqbound(func, x0, bounds, args = (), **kw):
    """
    Constrained multivariant Levenberg-Marquard optimization

    Minimize the sum of squares of a given function using the 
    Levenberg-Marquard algorithm. Contraints on parameters are inforced using 
    variable transformations as described in the MINUIT User's Guide by
    Fred James and Matthias Winkler.

    Parameters:

    * func      functions to call for optimization.
    * x0        Starting estimate for the minimization.
    * bounds    (min,max) pair for each element of x, defining the bounds on
                that parameter.  Use None for one of min or max when there is
                no bound in that direction.
    * args      Any extra arguments to func are places in this tuple.

    Returns: (x,{cov_x,infodict,mesg},ier)

    Return is described in the scipy.optimize.leastsq function.  x and con_v  
    are corrected to take into account the parameter transformation, infodic 
    is not corrected.

    Additional keyword arguments are passed directly to the 
    scipy.optimize.leastsq algorithm. 

    """
    # check for full output
    if "full_output" in kw and kw["full_output"]:
        full = True
    else:
        full = False

    # convert x0 to internal variables
    i0 = external2internal(x0, bounds)

    # perfrom unconstrained optimization using internal variables
    r = leastsq(err, i0, args = (bounds, func, args), **kw)

    # unpack return convert to external variables and return
    if full:
        xi, cov_xi, infodic, mesg, ier = r
        xe = internal2external(xi, bounds)
        cov_xe = i2e_cov_x(xi, bounds, cov_xi)
        # XXX correct infodic 'fjac','ipvt', and 'qtf' 
        return xe, cov_xe, infodic, mesg, ier

    else:
        xi, ier = r
        xe = internal2external(xi, bounds)
        return xe, ier


# new below

def _evaluate(x, p):
    '''
    Linear plus Lorentzian curve
    p = list with three parameters ([a, b, I, Pos, FWHM])
    '''
    return p[0] + p[1] * x + p[2] / (1 + np.power((x - p[3]) / (p[4] / 2), 2))


def residuals(p, y, x):

    err = _evaluate(x, p) - y
    return err


if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt('constraint.dat') # read data

    p0 = [5000., 0., 500., 2450., 3] #Start values for a, b, I, Pos, FWHM
    constraints = [(4000., None), (-50., 20.), (0., 2000.), (2400., 2451.), (None, None)]

    p, res = leastsqbound(residuals, p0, constraints, args = (data[:, 1], data[:, 0]), maxfev = 20000)
    print p, res

    plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1]) # plot data
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], _evaluate(data[:, 0], p0)) # plot start values
    plt.plot(data[:, 0], _evaluate(data[:, 0], p)) # plot fit values
    plt.show()
```

Thats the plot output, where green is the starting conditions and red the fit result:
[image: plot results]

Is this the correct usage? External2internal conversion just throws a nan if outside the bounds. leastsq seems to be able to handle this?

I uploaded the fitting data [here](http://pastebin.com/cn6kR6Lf). Just paste into a text file named constraint.dat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an existing popular constrained Lev-Mar code

http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ASPC..411..251M

with the implementation in python

http://code.google.com/p/astrolibpy/source/browse/mpfit/mpfit.py

I would suggest not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. I did not find any reference to mpfit before, and it looks its exactly what I try to achieve. But how would a minimal working example look like? The usage is different from scipy's leastsq. It seems the x and y values are not passed, but instead the reference? The example in mpfit.py is also not working.

Comment: Here is the example, which definitely works:
http://code.google.com/p/astrolibpy/source/browse/mpfit/tests/test_mpfit.py

Comment: I used the first example from the testfile you linked to get the solution below running. I was initially a bit confused because they use start values _p0 = [1, 1]_ but  in the parameter dictionary _parinfo_ they use 3.2 and 1.78. Also, _p0_ is actually not necessary in the call.

Comment: Please see also my other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11330131/334287): mpfit.py does not fit properly. Scipy.odr does.

Answer (score 0):

Following sega_sai's answer I came up with this minimal working example using mpfit.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpfit import mpfit
import numpy as np

def _evaluate(p, x):
    '''
    Linear plus Lorentzian curve
    p = list with three parameters ([a, b, I, Pos, FWHM])
    '''
    return p[0] + p[1] * x + p[2] / (1 + np.power((x - p[3]) / (p[4] / 2), 2))

def residuals(p, fjac = None, x = None, y = None, err = None):
    status = 0
    error = _evaluate(p, x) - y
    return [status, error / err]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.loadtxt('constraint.dat') # read data
    x = data[:, 0]
    y = data[:, 1]
    err = 0 * np.ones(y.shape, dtype = 'float64')
    parinfo = [{'value':5000., 'fixed':0, 'limited':[0, 0], 'limits':[0., 0.], 'parname':'a'},
               {'value':0., 'fixed':0, 'limited':[0, 0], 'limits':[0., 0.], 'parname':'b'},
               {'value':500., 'fixed':0, 'limited':[0, 0], 'limits':[0., 0.], 'parname':'I'},
               {'value':2450., 'fixed':0, 'limited':[0, 0], 'limits':[0., 0.], 'parname':'Pos'},
               {'value':3., 'fixed':0, 'limited':[0, 0], 'limits':[0., 0.], 'parname':'FWHM'}]
    fa = {'x':x, 'y':y, 'err':err}
    m = mpfit(residuals, parinfo = parinfo, functkw = fa)
    print m
```

The fit results are:

```
mpfit.py: 3714.97545, 0.484193283, 2644.47271, 2440.13385, 22.1898496
leastsq:  3714.97187, 0.484194545, 2644.46890, 2440.13391, 22.1899295
```

So conclusion: Both methods work, both allow constraints. But as mpfit comes from a very established sourceI trust it more. Also it honors error values, if available.

Answer (score 0):

Try lmfit-py - https://github.com/newville/lmfit-py

1. It also uses the Levenberg-Marquardt (LM) algorithm via scipy.optimize.leastsq. Uncertaintes are OK.
2. It allows you not only to constrain your fitting parameters with bounds but also with mathematical expressions between them without modification of your fitting function.
3. Forget about using those awful p[0], p[1] ... in fitting function. Just use names of the fitting parameters via the Parameters class.